# is it possible to get coordinates for image mapping without using image mapping software?

Tags: css, html, image, google-maps

I am learning html/css and one thing that baffles me is the idea of image mapping, how am i suppose to get the coordinates of a section of an image and plug it into my area tag without using image mapping software like gimp. Using gimp's image map tool is really useful but I am concerned that i will need to know how to do this without gimp in the future for some special situation i can't  think of, is there a way to get coordinates without image mapping software? Should i be concerned about relying on image mapping software?

thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the coordinates of a clicked point in an image by using JavaScript:

```js
$('.clickable').bind('click', function (ev) {
    var $div = $(ev.target);
    var $display = $div.find('.display');

    var offset = $div.offset();
    var x = ev.clientX - offset.left;
    var y = ev.clientY - offset.top;

    $display.text('x: ' + x + ', y: ' + y);
});
```

```css
.clickable {
    background-image: url("http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/0/0e/Googleplex-Patio-Aug-2014.JPG/300px-Googleplex-Patio-Aug-2014.JPG");
    height: 150px;
    width: 150px;
    margin: 15px;
    position: absolute;
}

.display {
    display: block;
    height: 16px;
    position: absolute;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
    width: 100%;
    top: 50%;
    margin-top: -8px;
    color: white;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='clickable'>
    <span class='display'></span>
</div>
```

**Demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/LQqGS/223/

Comment: awesome thanks! I have not dipped into java script yet but good to know.